# How to setup Mongodb on Ubuntu 16?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to install mongodb in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS using these instruction:

[Install MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

When I m trying to run the command

```
mongod
```

from the terminal i get the following error:

```
2016-06-28T17:55:05.299+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1982 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=rasik
    2016-06-28T17:55:05.299+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.7
    2016-06-28T17:55:05.299+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 4249c1d2b5999ebbf1fdf3bc0e0e3b3ff5c0aaf2
    2016-06-28T17:55:05.299+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
    2016-06-28T17:55:05.299+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
    2016-06-28T17:55:05.299+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
    2016-06-28T17:55:05.299+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
    2016-06-28T17:55:05.299+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1404
    2016-06-28T17:55:05.299+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
    2016-06-28T17:55:05.299+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
    2016-06-28T17:55:05.299+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
    2016-06-28T17:55:05.447+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
    2016-06-28T17:55:05.447+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
    a
```

How to I fix it ?

UPDATE:

I m getting this warning how to fix this :

```
Server has startup warnings: 
2016-06-28T22:01:51.482+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-06-28T22:01:51.482+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2016-06-28T22:01:51.482+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-06-28T22:01:51.482+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-06-28T22:01:51.482+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-06-28T22:01:51.482+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-06-28T22:01:51.482+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

Comment: Hi there. I see you deleted [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39084249/472495), which had the effect of throwing away Levi's help to you. We tend to discourage this, since it isn't nice for people to have their efforts deleted. Would you reinstate it?

Comment: @halfer i deleted it bcuz i figured out the solution

Comment: Yeah, that's not how it works here, really. The price of asking a question is making an effort to formulate an answer, which may be helpful to someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongo is looking for the default data directory /data/db, which does not exist.
You can either create /data/db or in fact create any subfolder in a folder you already own. Then try

```
mongod --dbpath pathtosubfolder
```

To start the server.
Then in a different terminal start the client shell:

```
mongo
```

This should work.

Comment: So after running that command i m getting a couple of warnings how to i fix those

Comment: The warnings are normal, usually you don't have to worry about them

Answer (score 2):

Pay attentention to do what it says:

```
 Data directory /data/db not found
```

That directory does not exist, over there MongoDB stores the data. You need to create it:

```
mkdir -R /data/db
```

and be sure that the user has read write access.