# Logging in an already-registered user in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, authentication

I have made the registration part of the login system, but I am unable to make a registered user login. How can I do this?

Here's my code:

#### Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.views.generic import View


from .forms import UserForm

# def Success(request):
#     return render(request, 'success.html')

class UserFormView(View):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'form.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            # cleaned data
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user.save()
            return redirect('success.html')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

#### Urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin


from .views import UserFormView


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', UserFormView.as_view(), name='registraion'),
    url(r'login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    #url(r'success/', Success, name='sccuess')
]
```

#### Forms.html

```
 Registration Form
<br>
<form action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
<button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

What I basically want is a login page from which I can login in an already-registered user (this login page is different from the page where the user registers). So basically a new view through which a registered user can log in.

I have already made the registration page and the code for it is above. Also after the user is authenticated on the login page he must be redirected to another page (say home.html) and his login information must also we carried to the page where he has been redirected to.

Comment: No, your question is not urgent - we get a few people every day who believe that their failure to plan may result in volunteers being asked to treat the word as important. Everyone wants an answer promptly, so the best solution is not to add this sort of begging, especially by vandalising their question title. [On this topic, please read this community discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495).

Comment: @halfer It would have been better if you would have answered this question as well rather than just commenting on it

Comment: It sounds like you either haven't read the link I have supplied, or you have read it and still don't care that you do not understand how to address **volunteers**. I notice you've even tried a write-it-for-me in response to an answer below - this is not how it works here. Volunteers are here to help you, they are not here to do the work for you, and they are certainly not here to do your work urgently.

Comment: @halfer  I read the link but that doesn't mean that you can go on whosoever question and put a comment on it and whats with the dislike there is nothing wrong with the way the question has been asked nor there is a problem with the code which has been put with it just because i used the word urgent doesn't mean that i m begging or anything + it wud have better if u wud have answered and then told me what i shud have done u ppl are just here to earn reputation

Comment: You are compounding your one rudeness with another, and you are quite wrong about my wanting reputation points - I spend most of my time improving posts from overly entitled and impatient individuals who seem to have limited desire to respect the community. I get zero reputation points from that. I do it because I think the community here is (mostly) great, and I don't seek reward for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use  `authenticate()` and `login()` after create your user.

Also, use `HttpResponseRedirect` to redirect user to your landing page, I think, you don't need to create a "success.html".

```
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            # cleaned data
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user.save()
            auth_user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(self.request, auth_user)
            # redirect works for 
            return  HttpResponseRedirect('your_landing_url')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Comment: do i need a separate url for success.html in ulrs.py ?

Comment: if you cud just write the whole view class for authentication it wud be great i m new to django so i'm in real trouble write now thanks in advance

Comment: Why are we saving the user response in the database like dont we just need to do that when we are registering him ?

Comment: @Rasik can you restructure your question ?